# How to join a Series to a DataFrame?

Tags: python, join, pandas, dataframe

Is there any way to join a Series to a DataFrame directly?

The join would be on a field of the dataframe and on the index of the series.

The only way I found was to convert the series to a dataframe first, as in the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = np.arange(0, 4)
df['b'] = np.arange(100, 104)


s = pd.Series(data=np.arange(100, 103))

# this doesn't work
# myjoin = pd.merge(df, s, how='left', left_on='a', right_index=True)

# this does
s = s.reset_index()
# s becomes a Dataframe
# note you cannot reset the index of a series inplace
myjoin = pd.merge(df, s, how='left', left_on='a', right_on='index')

print myjoin
```

Comment: Sorry are you asking just to add a new column e.g.: `df['new_col'] = df['a'].map(s)`?

Comment: I believe the solution in your question (to make `s` a dataframe with `reset_index()`) is the correct solution.

Comment: I want to add the column in the Series to the dataframe, but how do I specify whether it should be a left outer join or an inner join, and how do I specify which column of the dataframe the index of the series should match? Thanks

Comment: In your case, you should use pd.join instead of pd.merge. The documentation says quite clearly: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandasdocs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html
But you should define the name of series before combine two.

Answer (score 6):

I guess http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html might help.

For example inner/outer join.

```
pd.concat((df,s), axis=1)
Out[26]: 
   a    b    0
0  0  100  100
1  1  101  101
2  2  102  102
3  3  103  NaN

In [27]: pd.concat((df,s), axis=1, join='inner')
Out[27]: 
   a    b    0
0  0  100  100
1  1  101  101
2  2  102  102
```

Comment: Does this join on the indices? In my case, the indices are different, and I want to specify the fields to join on, but concat doesn't seem to have on, left_on, right_on parameters like pd.merge does

Comment: Yes, it joins on indexes. Solves only this part >> I want to add the column in the Series to the dataframe, but how do I specify whether it should be a left outer join or an inner join

Comment: mmm, so is the only way to convert from series to dataframe with reset_index? This converts the index to a column, which gets added to the result of the merge function. I'd therefore need to remove it. It all seems needlessly convoluted!

Comment: Don't really know, maybe there is some other way, but i don't know it and can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very late answer, but what worked for me was building a dataframe with the columns you want to retrieve in your series, name this series as the index you need,
append the series to the dataframe (if you have supplementary elements in the series they are added to the dataframe, which in some application may be convenient), then join the final dataframe by this index to the original dataframe you want to expand. Agreed it is not direct, but that's still the most convenient way if you have a lot of series, instead of transforming each in a dataframe first.

Answer (score -1):

Try concat():

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame()
df['a']= np.arange(0,4)
df['b']= np.arange(100,104)

s =pd.Series(data = np.arange(100,103))

new_df = pd.concat((df, s), axis=1)
print new_df
```

This prints:

```
   a    b    0
0  0  100  100
1  1  101  101
2  2  102  102
3  3  103  NaN
```